# DataTables - need to sort integer column but put 0s and empty cells at the bottom

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm relatively new to DataTables but I've got one working with one exception: I have a two columns of ranking information (integer-only, 1-500+) and while it sorts fine ordinarily, it puts blank cells and zeros at the top when they should always be at the bottom.

I've seen a few threads where people wrote custom sorting plug-ins but none of them work for me.

Currently I'm using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datatable").dataTable( {
    bFilter: false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 9 ] }, { sType: 'datetime-us-flex', aTargets: [0, 4, 5] }, { sType: 'numeric-empty-bottom', aTargets: [7, 8] }
    ],"iDisplayLength": 25, 
  });
});
```

With this plugin:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-empty-bottom-asc": function ( x, y ) {
        if ( "" == x ) return 1;
        if ( "" == y ) return -1;
        return parseFloat( x ) - parseFloat( y );
    },
    "numeric-empty-bottom-desc": function ( y, x ) {
        if ( "" == x ) return 1;
        if ( "" == y ) return -1;
        return parseFloat( x ) - parseFloat( y );
    }
});
```

However, the result seems to be completely random and I don't know enough about sorting plugins to make heads or tales of it. My datetime-us-flex does work properly so I'm pretty sure I'm implementing the plugins correctly.

HTML (by request):

```
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Start Date</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Rank FA</td>
      <td>Rank FC</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Start Date</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Rank FA</td>
      <td>Rank FC</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9713">10/03/2014</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9713">Item #1</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9713">358</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9713">370</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=10361">10/04/2014</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=10361">Item #2</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=10361">500</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=10361">491</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=61555">10/04/2014</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=61555">Item #3</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=61555">0</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=61555">0</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9753">10/25/2014</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9753">Item #4</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9753">487</a></td>
      <td><a href="/datasheet?id=9753">469</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of a sorting plugin, I [once](https://github.com/davidkonrad/datatables-sort-numbers-ignore-text/blob/master/sort-numbers-ignore-text.js) made for another project :

```
function testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, high) {
    var reg = /[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;    
    a = $(a).text().match(reg);
    a = a !== null && parseInt(a[0])!==0 ? parseInt(a[0]) : high;
    b = $(b).text().match(reg);
    b = b !== null && parseInt(b[0])!==0 ? parseInt(b[0]) : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));    
}
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-empty-bottom-asc": function (a, b) {
        return testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    },
    "numeric-empty-bottom-desc": function (a, b) {
        return testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) * -1;
    }
});
```

This would put `0` and text columns (blanks) at the bottom, both when sorting ascending and descending. The trick is to return the lowest possible integer when sorting ascending, the highest integer when sorting descending.

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dowbsc4t/**

---

Updated to take care of the columns is wrapped into `<a>`..`</a>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, but it seems to not be working.  When I apply the plugin it now sorts randomly: 295-102-138-392-553-0, then flipped when I flip the sort.  I added an alert("true") to the function and I get a proper response, so I know the function is being called when I click those columns.

Comment: hey @SeanCunningham, weird - hopefully the fiddle works, also for you? I was wondering, are the columns containing integers perhaps wrapped into some HTML? like `<span>123</span>` or similar?

Comment: Ahh, that's it -- I'm using links in each table cell and passing along the record's unique ID. So it appears that it's sorting on the first integer it finds.  Wow, any idea how I could modify this to ignore the A tag?

Comment: Hey @SeanCunningham, could you update your question with an example of the markup? Or just post it here as a comment? Just how a column looks like.

Comment: Sorry, should have included that from the beginning.

Comment: @SeanCunningham, sorry - have not noticed you have updated the question :( See updated answer, the fiddle is now with your HTML, if it is any worth and you havent solved the problem yourself. It is the same, just with the difference that the data is extracted from the links with a = `$(a).text().match(reg);` etc